# Stop CSS drop-down menu from closing on click inside

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a CSS drop-down menu I am using that works fine, the only thing is that I want to stop the menu from closing when you click anywhere inside the menu.

Right now, it closes anytime you click inside the main-nav, which makes it difficult to click links, etc.

It is currently live on our website, www.jonasconstruction.com. If necessary I can attach the full code here.

Thanks.

```
<div class="top-menu top-menu-mobile">
  <header class="dark">
    <nav class="navigate"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic opened"> 
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic closed"></a>
          <ul class="main-nav"></a> 
              <li class="top-level-link"> 
                  <a class="mega-menu" href="/products">
                        <span>Products</span></a> 
               <div class="sub-menu-block"> 
               <div class="row">
```

Comment: No need to give full code. If you could extract only the needed pieces, that would be fine. ( That means, try to recreate the issue with as minimal amount of code as possible )

Comment: On Chrome Mac -- not having that issue.

Comment: <div class="top-menu top-menu-mobile"><header class="dark"><nav class="navigate"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic opened"> <span class="line"></span> <span class="line"></span> <span class="line"></span></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ic closed"> </a><ul class="main-nav"></a> <li class="top-level-link"> <a class="mega-menu" href="/products"><span>Products</span></a> <div class="sub-menu-block"> <div class="row">

Comment: I would suggest adding a jsfiddle link -- not place the code in the comment section

Comment: @SpencerRohan Chrome and Firefox on Windows both have this issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/20ddr264/

Comment: Your ul and a tags seem to be jumbled. <ul class="main-nav"></a>  You need an li between those

Comment: It seems to be working fine, aside from it closing on click.

Comment: Your JSFiddle and code snippet you placed in the comments are different. This is also for the mobile menu. Any way you can unminify the css?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/20ddr264/3/

Comment: The issue is coming from your html markup. It looks like you have a couple of spots that are opening tags and never closing them. Opening new tags and closing a different tag. I would suggest crawling through your html first and sorting out those few issues.  It only happens on the submenu sections for me(the clicking closes the menu) and I believe that stems from you not utilizing the li tags correctly. Also, there appears to be a few divs that aren't doing anything but opening and closing(like div class="row"). Crawl through and ensure your markup is correct and I think it'll resolve.

Answer (score 0):

HTML markup is missing some closing tags in a few places. The submenu div is where this issue is occurring. I would first crawl through the html markup and ensure proper tag etiquette is used.  Then I would make your sub menu into list items(but style them different than your top level list items). This should extend the link area the width of the menu, allowing for this issue to resolve.

Comment: It doesn't seem to really stop the issue. I can extend the menu width for when a link is clicked, but there is still the ability to click away from the menu and it will close. There was 1 or 2 span tags that weren't closed properly, but other than that the HTML looks fine.

Comment: I'm only noticing this problem on the submenu section -- the section under products. Does it happen anywhere else?

Comment: Basically on the mobile menu, when u click anything aside from a link the menu will close. Not sure what is triggering the menu to close. This is a problem, because if u hit any button the menu will close, which is not ideal.

Comment: I'm not seeing that issue in the  jsfiddle. It doesn't have that issue, except in the products section.  The live site I see what you are referring to however. Is it possible the code snippet is different than the live site?